# Virtual host setup in localhost using Docker on Ubuntu. magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.1

I'm trying to convert `http://localhost/magento231/` to `http://testing.com` and for admin `http://testing.com/admin` I followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts but it was not useful for me. How can I change my **Visual Host**?

Comment: what exactly you did to try to fix this issue?

Comment: I tried the above link but it was not on the Docker so it gives me issues. I'm using M2.3.1 on Docker n I want to change the the host